# Analog audio recognized by ALSA, but not by PulseAudio

Tags: 12.04, sound, pulseaudio, hdmi, alsa

I'm running Ubuntu 12.04 on Zotac ID84

sudo aplay -l:

```
card 0: Intel [HDA Intel], device 0: ALC892 Analog [ALC892 Analog]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: Intel [HDA Intel], device 1: ALC892 Digital [ALC892 Digital]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 7: HDMI 1 [HDMI 1]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

sudo aplay /usr/share/sounds/alsa/Front_Center.wav:

```
Playing WAVE '/usr/share/sounds/alsa/Front_Center.wav' : Signed 16 bit Little Endian, Rate 48000 Hz, Mono
```

the sound is really played on the speakers!

But in the list of devices on PulseAudio GUI control panel I see only

- Digital Output (S/PDIF)
- HDMI / DisplayPort

When I select HDMI, I hear sound through HDMI correctly. When I select Digital Output, I hear nothing (as expected). Can somebody tell me please how to find the "Analog Output" option?

**UPDATE** I reinstalled the system from scratch. Now I still see no "Analog Output" option in the list of devices, but while *no device is selected* in the list, I enjoy listening sound through speakers. If now I choose anything from the list, then I cannot "unselect" it and sound won't play again... so my question is still relevant.

Comment: Please post the output of `pactl list` and `pactl info`.

Comment: can you give more detail as to what you exactly want?

Comment: this same problem is happening for me in 13.10

Comment: I just hit the same wall in Mint 17.  Everything was working perfectly for almost a year--then I shut the laptop off, took it to a presentation, hooked it up to a projector (which played sound), then brought it back home and found my analog audio ports dead.  mplayer from the command-line works, so does aplay.  Even VLC in the GUI works.  But seemingly nothing that talks with PulseAudio including Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it on my box.  I think there's something wrong with pulse audio and the sound card (maybe problems with an updated driver) or maybe something with the pavucontrol application.  Either way, I had to tell PulseAudio to stop looking for my sound card and just play everything through Alsa.

I ran `aplay -l | grep card` to find the specific sound card I wanted, then I edited `/etc/pulse/default.pa` and added a line `load-module module-alsa-sink device=hw:0,0` where the 'hw:0,0' corresponds to the card found in the aplay -l command.  Restart PulseAudio or reboot the system and give it a shot.

Note: I noticed Pulse doesn't recognize my built-in webcam or the audio at the moment either.  *sigh*