# sound issues on fresh 16.04 install

Tags: sound, pulseaudio

Here is the setup:

- I have integrated audio on my mother board, onto which my speakers are connected by a 3.5mm jack
- I have a video card with HDMI output (Radeon HD 5700 Series), but I use the DVI ports, not HDMI. So no sound this way really
- I have a USB headset with microphone.

Problem summary:

- when logged in, in Settings > Sound > Output , I only have HDMI / DisplayPort and the Headphones. The sound works via headphones, but I do not have any actual audio device on the HDMI. So my speakers do not get any sound.
- on boot, the startup sound does play via the speakers (I can hear the drum like sound!).

All 3 devices are detected:

```
pacmd list-cards | grep alsa.long_card_name
        alsa.long_card_name = "HDA ATI HDMI at 0xfbcfc000 irq 32"
        alsa.long_card_name = "HDA Intel MID at 0xfbbf8000 irq 31"
        alsa.long_card_name = "Logitech Logitech USB Headset at usb-0000:00:1d.0-1.6, full speed"
```

And:

```
aplay -l
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: MID [HDA Intel MID], device 0: VT1828S Analog [VT1828S Analog]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: MID [HDA Intel MID], device 2: VT1828S Alt Analog [VT1828S Alt Analog]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: MID [HDA Intel MID], device 3: VT1828S Digital [VT1828S Digital]
  Subdevices: 0/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: Headset [Logitech USB Headset], device 0: USB Audio [USB Audio]
  Subdevices: 0/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 2: HDMI [HDA ATI HDMI], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 0/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

So the question really is, how can I add the built-in audio (with my speakers) to the Settings > Audio > Output list?

The Built-in Audio is seen in pavucontrol but the profile doesn't seem right. I tried changing it to Analogue Stereo Output but it doesn't seem to work and removes the Built-in Audio entry from "output devices"

Some screenshots to help:
[Volume Control - Configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9mW7l.png)
[Volume Control - Output Devices](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t0xXm.png)

Comment: Related: http://askubuntu.com/questions/317022/analog-audio-recognized-by-alsa-but-not-by-pulseaudio

Answer (score 0):

Using the link provided by Elder Geek, non validated answer worked for me:

I added the below to /etc/pulse/default.pa (well uncommented the line with load-module module-alsa-sink and added the device bit)
load-module module-alsa-sink device=hw:0,0

Then restarted the system, after which the Built-in audio was present in Settings > Sound!
Selecting it made it work...